# Rails 3 route -> to #show. Default ID if nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to route the root of my project to the books#show action.  And have the ID of the book be dynamic.

But I don't want it to affect the standard show action.

ie... (this code does not work of course :)

```
  def show
    if  @book.id is present?
        @book = Book.find(params[:id])                       
    else
        @book = Book.first
    end
  end
```

I hope this makes sense.

Basically, I want to be able to view any Book by its ID.  But if no Id is specified, have it default to Book.first.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close. Try using `params[:id].present?` as your `if` condition, and it should get what you want.

You'll need a `root :to => "books#show"` route in your routes.rb to make it work.

However, from a clarity standpoint, I'd just have two actions: your normal show, and a `home` action, which reads something like:

```
def home
  @book = Book.first
  render :action => "show"
end

def show
  @book = Book.find(params[:id])
end
```

Then, in your routes.rb:

```
root :to => "books#home"
```

This will let you keep the two actions clean, and more directly communicate the intent of those actions.

Comment: Deleting my answer, because this approach is cleaner and far more readable :)

Comment: Thanks Chris!  The codefix works.  But it makes absolutely perfect sense to split them up...  Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry bout that.  It makes you wait 10 minutes to accept.  So I ran an errand real quick.  Perfect answer.  Thanks again for your help...